# oracle forms not showing all fields

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have 2 tables: product which has primary key product_id and Review which has product_id which references the product_id of product table;
I created form master-detail for them but when executing I get at the bottom of page:

> **FRM-40505:** *ORACLE error: unable to perform query*

and when pressing ctrl+shift+e I get:

```
SELECT ROWID, REVIEW_ID, LIKE, DISLIKE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PRODUCT_ID 
  FROM U1.REVIEW WHERE (PRODUCT_ID=:1)

ORA-00936: missing expression
```

how to solve this? what is wrong? thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems you have a field named `like` in your block with base table named `review` has `Database Item` set to `Yes` in the property palette, and for this reason Oracle treats that field as if a column of the table, but there's no such column, and not possible to have a column named `like` within a db table, since it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I agree; how did you (@mark080) manage to create such a table? If you used double quotes around the `LIKE` column, well - you shouldn't be doing that. If you insist, enclose that column name into double quotes again, e.g. `select "LIKE", dislike, ...`

Comment: No problem, Barbaros :)